# Why I can't send pdf with jersey to a browser client?

Tags: java, pdf, jersey, jax-rs

I've a problem: I want to edit a pdf in the webservice and send the edited pdf to the client via jersey. The problem is, if I call the url in a browser it says that there was an error while loading the PDF.

I've already tried to set the response type to something else than pdf and I also tried another pdf from the internet.

```
@Path("/certificate")
public class CertificateService{
    @GET
    @Path("{language}/{name}")
    @Produces("application/pdf")
    public Response createPDF(@PathParam("language") String language,@PathParam("name") String name) throws IOException {


        PDDocument document = null;
        try {
            // Load the document and get the AcroForm

            DateFormat formatter;
            URL url = new URL("http://app-learning.com/simplestock/assets/Zertifikat-de.pdf");
                    BufferedInputStream file = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                    document = document.load(file);

                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");


            PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
            PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();


            // Fill the text field
            PDTextField field1 = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField("Text1");
            field1.setValue(name);
            // Optional: don't allow this field to be edited
            field1.setReadOnly(true);

            Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();


            String today = formatter.format(c);

            PDTextField field2 = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField("Text2");
            field2.setValue(today);
            // Optional: don't allow this field to be edited
            field2.setReadOnly(true);






        } catch (IOException e) {

        }



      final File file = File.createTempFile("certi", ".pdf");
      document.save(file);
      document.close();



        return Response.ok(file).header("Content-Disposition",  "filename=restfile.pdf").type("application/pdf").build();


    }
```

Comment: Are you able to get the error message? That would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: What is the meaning of "want to edit a pdf in the webservice" ?

Comment: @Sambit I edited the pdf on the server side

Comment: @AustinSchäfer Jersey doesn't provides any error and if I load the url in the chrome browser it says the there was an error while loading the pdf

Comment: Ok, it means, you are facing problem in sending the pdf file to the client. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: My suggestion will be just separate the code for editing pdf file and try to send to client. It means have one static pdf file in one location, in a rest call, you should be able to send the pdf file to the client to download.

Comment: Check in browser what status your service returns, 200 or 5xx, and tell us.